# Time Complexity of Code for finding longest word inside dictionary

Tags: java, string, recursion, time, time-complexity

Problem is as follows: You start with a 2 letter word, and you can append letters to the front and back of the word. You have to return the longest word that exists inside a dictionary that you can form by appending letters to the front and back of the 2 letter word, and every new word that you formed must also be inside the dictionary as well

For example:
Start: 'at'

Dict: [hat, chat, chats, rat, rate, orange]

Output: 'chats', because: at -> hat -> chat -> chats

I have the code as follows:

```
public static String longest(ArrayList<String> input) {    
    return helper('at', dict);
}


public static String helper(String in, ArrayList<String> dict) {

    ArrayList<String> maxes = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (char a = 'a'; a < 'z'; a++) {
      String front = Character.toString(a) + in;
      String back = in + Character.toString(a);
      if (dict.contains(front)) {
        maxes.add(helper(front, dict));
      }
      if (dict.contains(back)) {
        maxes.add(helper(back, dict));
      }
    }

    if (maxes.size() == 0) {
      return in;
    } 

    String word = "";
    for (String w : maxes) {
      if (w.length() > word.length()) {
        word = w;
      }
    }
    return word;
  }
```

I was wondering what the time complexity for this algorithm would be? I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-algorithm-set-4-master-method-solving-recurrences/

Comment: Comment, as it doesn't answer the question about your algorithm -- but I think I would work this backward, assuming the intention is that this works with a full-length dictionary. Preprocess the dictionary into a digraph of (ap/pre)pend chains. Then to check a word, just find children of the input node.

Answer (score 2):

The answer strongly depends on your dictionary (*n* words with max reachable length *L*<=*n*+1) and on your data structure for storing it.  Each call to `helper` (without its recursive calls) is O(*n L*) with `dict` being an `ArrayList`, whereas with a hash table it's O(*L*) (absent unlikely collisions).  (There can be very long unreachable words in the dictionary, but it still costs only O(*L*) to compare against them because your trial words can't be longer.)

As for the number of calls to `helper`: this is just a depth-first search on the tree of words related by prepending/appending a letter.  As such, it's O(*v*), where *v* is the number of vertices visited.  The values of *v* for various input words depends on your dictionary as well: *v*<=*n*, of course, and is often much less.  As an example: using the 71813 lines in my `/usr/share/dict/words` that are all ASCII letters (and ignoring case), the most words ever considered is 593 (for "Ar" as in argon).

The worst-case dictionary will have all its words forming a chain "ab", "abc", "abcd", *etc.*.  You visit every word for a total cost of O(*v n L*)=O(*n*^3) (O(*v L*)=O(*n*^2) with the hash table).  Realistic dictionaries will be much faster not only because *L* is smaller but also because *v* is; the exact speedup is unfortunately difficult to analyze.  It's probably reasonable to assume *L* is Θ(log(*n*)); there's no meaningful asymptotic expression for *v* as a function of *n* because *realistic* dictionaries don't have arbitrarily large *n*.

Comment: Does it even really depend on the dictionary? When calculating O(n) doesn't you just assume worst case to get an upper bound? I take it the whole thing is: O(vertices-visited), and that a 'vertex' is each time helper() is called?

Comment: @Adam: It depends on the dictionary (whose size is the obvious _n_) because the input word (or even all possible input words) might be an ancestor of a vanishing subset of a large dictionary.  (Consider one with no three-letter words!)  Of course it's still O(n) (assuming the `dict.contains()` is fast), but the point is that for a realistic dictionary that might be pessimistic beyond the usual "worst case" analysis.  (Yes, each call is a vertex because it expands on one word.)

Comment: Ok, that clears it up a bit! I'd still find an example of a worst-case dictionary to be interesting/enlightening as to how'd you'd go about solving something like this. (Can't remove downvote until edit)

Comment: @DavisHerring , thanks for your response. What is the maximum reachable length L? Is it the length of the longest word in the dictionary?

Comment: @clueless_wanderer: As the answer says, _L_<=_n_+1 (assuming that your starting word must be in the dictionary).  Each new word is only one letter longer than the previous, after all.  Longer words can be present, but (after a bit of thinking) you can see that they don't even cost more time.